# Spark Thrift Server and Tableau

Tags: apache-spark, thrift, tableau-api

​I have been successful in integrating Tableau with Spark Thrift Server using Samba ODBC. I have tried using the `cache table` during the *Initial SQL* and the performance has been great till now. I am now looking for a way to cache and un cache few of the frequently used tables when they are updated using through our data pipelines.

The challlenge that I am facing is that the cache table done via Tableau will remain in cache through the lifetime of the thrift server but when I write my data pipleline process and submit spark jobs it will use a different spark context. 
Can anyone please suggest how can I connect to the thrift server context through the backend process.

1. Is there a way to re-use the thrift services from spark-submit or spark shell?
2. At the end of my data pipeline will it be a good idea to invoke a simple shell script that will connect to the thrift service and refresh the cache?

**Note:** both my backend and the BI tool are using the same cluster as I have used the same yarn cluster while starting the thrift service as well as submitting the backend jobs.

Thanks, Jayadeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [beeline](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-Beeline%E2%80%93CommandLineShell) to connect to the Thrift Service on the same cluster using the same URL & credentials. Once the data Pipeline completes run

```
UNCACHE TABLE MyTable;
CACHE TABLE MyTable;
```